# How to apply Closed-Open and Inversion of Control principles in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture, clean-architecture

Building out a new application now and struggling a lot with the implementation part of "Closed-Open" and "Inversion of Control" principles I following after reading Clean Architecture book by Uncle Bob.

**How can I implement them in Python?**

Usually, these two principles coming hand in hand and depicted in the UML as an `Interface` reversing control from module/package A to B.

I'm confused because:

- Python does not possess `Interface`s as Java and C++ do. Yes, there are `ABC` and `@abstractmethod`, but it is not a Pythonic style and redundant from my point of view if you are not developing a framework
- Passing a class to the method of another one (I understood that it is a way to implement open-closed principle) is a little bit dangerous in Python, since it does not have a compiler which is catching issues may (and will) happen if one of two loosely coupled objects change
- After neglecting interfaces and passing a top-level class to lower-level ones... I still need to import everything somewhere at the top module. And by that, the whole thing is violated.

So, as you can see I'm super confused and having a hard time programming according to my design. I came up with. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass an object that implements the methods you need it to implement.

True, there is no "Interface" to define what those methods have to be, but that's just the way it is in python.

You pass around arguments all the time that have to be lists, maps, tuples, or whatever, and none of these are type-checked.  You can write code that calls whatever you want on these things and python will not notice any kind of problem until that code is actually executed.

It's exactly the same when you need those arguments to implement whatever IoC interface you're using.  Make sure you detail the requirements in comments.

Yes, this is all pretty dangerous.  That's why we prefer statically typed languages for large systems that have complex interfaces.